# Conversion of xml file to PHP and use of multi-dimensional array's

Tags: php, arrays, xml, multidimensional-array, geocoding

I'm working on a project in which I need to convert XML file to PHP format, so that I could use the value's in the file. I used the following code:

```
$myarray = simplexml_load_file('/*xml file location*/');
```

The XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GeocodeResponse>
 <status>OK</status>
 <result>
  <type>locality</type>
  <type>political</type>
  <formatted_address>Vijayawada, Andhra Pradesh, India</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Vijayawada</long_name>
   <short_name>Vijayawada</short_name>
   <type>locality</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Krishna</long_name>
   <short_name>Krishna</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Andhra Pradesh</long_name>
   <short_name>AP</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>India</long_name>
   <short_name>IN</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>16.5061743</lat>
    <lng>80.6480153</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>16.4565307</lat>
     <lng>80.5572568</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>16.5639733</lat>
     <lng>80.7316657</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
   <bounds>
    <southwest>
     <lat>16.4565307</lat>
     <lng>80.5572568</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>16.5639733</lat>
     <lng>80.7316657</lng>
    </northeast>
   </bounds>
  </geometry>
  <place_id>ChIJS5QtSPnvNToRZQJKq4R-m5M</place_id>
 </result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

This gave me an PHP array output as:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [status] => OK 
                          [result] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                            [type] => Array ( 
                              [0] => locality [1] => political 
                            ) 
                            [formatted_address] => Vijayawada, Andhra Pradesh, India 
                            [address_component] => Array ( 
                              [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                                [long_name] => Vijayawada 
                                [short_name] => Vijayawada 
                                [type] => Array ( 
                                  [0] => locality 
                                  [1] => political 
                                 ) 
                               ) 
                              [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
                                [long_name] => Krishna 
                                [short_name] => Krishna 
                                [type] => Array ( 
                                   [0] => administrative_area_level_2 
                                   [1] => political 
                                 ) 
                               ) 
                               [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                                 [long_name] => Andhra Pradesh 
                                 [short_name] => AP 
                                 [type] => Array ( 
                                   [0] => administrative_area_level_1 
                                   [1] => political 
                                  ) 
                                ) 
                                [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
                                  [long_name] => India 
                                  [short_name] => IN 
                                  [type] => Array ( 
                                    [0] => country 
                                    [1] => political 
                                   ) 
                                 ) 
                               ) 
                               [geometry] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
                                 [location] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                                   [lat] => 16.5061743 
                                   [lng] => 80.6480153 
                                  ) 
                                 [location_type] => APPROXIMATE 
                                 [viewport] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                                   [southwest] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                                     [lat] => 16.4565307 
                                     [lng] => 80.5572568 
                                    ) 
                                    [northeast] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                                      [lat] => 16.5639733 
                                      [lng] => 80.7316657 
                                     )
                                   ) 
                                   [bounds] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                                   [southwest] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                                     [lat] => 16.4565307 
                                     [lng] => 80.5572568 
                                    ) 
                                    [northeast] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                                      [lat] => 16.5639733 
                                      [lng] => 80.7316657

                                     ) 
                                   ) 
                                 ) 
                                 [place_id] => ChIJS5QtSPnvNToRZQJKq4R-m5M 
                               ) 
                             )
```

Now, my question is : 
I need only the values of lat, lon of location part I.e.,

```
[geometry] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [location] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [lat] => 16.5061743 [lng] => 80.6480153 )
```

So,

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there's some missing details, I guess you want to retrieve the values? In that case, simplexml doesn't return an array but an object.

```
$myarray = simplexml_load_file('/*xml file location*/');
$lat = $myarray->result->geometry->location->lat;
$long = $myarray->result->geometry->location->lng
```